# How can I exclude data containing certain characters from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I exclude data containing certain characters from an array in JavaScript.

I want to exclude titles with specific strings. Strings are not multiple patterns. One.

For example, I have an array.

sample Array

```
[
    {
        "title": "aaa",
        "url": "https://aaa.com"
    },
    {
        "title": "bbb",
        "url": "https://bbb.com"
    },
        {
        "title": "ccc",
        "url": "https://ccc.com"
    },
]
```

I want to get an array like below.(exclude title: bbb)

```
[
    {
        "title": "aaa",
        "url": "https://aaa.com"
    },
    {
        "title": "ccc",
        "url": "https://ccc.com"
    },
]
```

Comment: given example is not better to understand . what you want to do ? please specify it more

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` method.

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "title": "aaa",
        "url": "https://aaa.com"
    },
    {
        "title": "bbb",
        "url": "https://bbb.com"
    },
        {
        "title": "ccc",
        "url": "https://ccc.com"
    },
]


let newArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.title !== "bbb")

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

use Array filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

from docs:

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```

in your case

```
const result = yourArray.filter(o => o.title !== 'bbb')
```